# spinner causes app to crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to make a spinner programmatically and after coding it the app started crashing. What i am trying to make is when an option from the spinner is selected the UI should change according to it. (newbie to android development)

Java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main_Page extends Activity {
int pos;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main__page);

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("Total Assets");
    array.add("Net Income");
    array.add("Cost of Goods Sold");
    array.add("Contribution Margin");
    array.add("Price Variance");
    array.add("Quantity Variance");

    LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
    spin.setPromptId(R.array.formulas);
    layout.addView(spin);
    spin.setLayoutParams(params);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array);
    spin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> nothing, View v, int position, long something)
        {
            pos = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> nothing)
        {

        }
    });



    if(pos==0)
    {

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Liabilities:");
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setHint("Enter liabilities value here");
        et.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Owner's Equity:");
        tv1.setLayoutParams(params);

        EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
        et1.setHint("Enter Owner's Equity value here");
        et1.setLayoutParams(params);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Find");
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);



        layout.addView(tv);
        layout.addView(et);
        layout.addView(tv1);
        layout.addView(et1);
        layout.addView(btn);



    }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    this.addContentView(layout, layoutParams);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__page, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Logcat:

```
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accountingsoftware/com.example.accountingsoftware.Main_Page}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060000
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060000
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:173)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.widget.Spinner.setPromptId(Spinner.java:285)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.example.accountingsoftware.Main_Page.onCreate(Main_Page.java:40)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-28 15:46:16.659: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Maybe your context is null?

Comment: Have you defined your array properly in your strings.xml file ?

Comment: use String[] instead of that arraylist , it might help

Comment: can you tell us the exact line where the error comes by using logcat..

Comment: Still crashes. Is it possible to add the spinner in xml and create the rest of the components programmatically. I tried it but the TextView and EditText fields cover the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spin.setPromptId(R.array.formulas);
```

`setPromptId()` expects a `R.string` resource, not `R.array`. This leads to the

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060000
```

(The NullPointerException in the logcat was from a previous version of your code as evidenced by logcat timestamps. I edited the question to remove irrelevant old exceptions.)

Comment: Is it this way: String [] str = new String [6];
  str[1] ="Total Assets";
  str[2]="Net Income";
  str[3]="Cost of Goods Sold";
  str[4]="Contribution Margin";
  str[5]="Price Variance";
  str[6]="Quantity Variance";Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
  spin.setPrompt(str+"");
  layout.addView(spin);
  spin.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: @user3026643 No, the prompt is just the spinner dialog title. Spinner options come from the adapter.

Comment: [http://s27.postimg.org/bp1txpnoj/Capture.png] this is the way the componets get displayed. Can u help me fix it?

Comment: @NohaPhilip That seems to be an issue with the layout. It's a separate issue from this spinner crash question. You can post another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `spin.setPromptId(R.array.formulas);` line the method gets the integer value and you are defining the `R.array`

Whereas it  `Sets the prompt to display when the dialog is shown.` so you should set the resource like `R.String.appname`.

Try out like this.

```
 spin.setPromptId(R.string.app_name);
```

Comment: didnt solve the problem. Can u tell me how to solve overlapping of components. Like if i make a spinner in main.xml and the rest of the components in .java file after running the program the components overlap each other.